# My NextJS site In local works fine, but when I deploy the site, Vercel don't upload my markdown files

Tags: next.js, deployment, build, markdown, vercel

I have a problem with Vercel deploying my NextJS site.
In local everything works fine, but when I deploy the site, Vercel don't upload my markdown files and then the site can't render them because it can't find them.

My .md files are in a folder named "posts" on the root. I have tried to move the folder inside the app directory but Vercel still doesn't upload the files when I do the deploy.

The code I'm using is:

```
import fs from "fs";
import matter from "gray-matter";

const getPostContent = (slug: string) => {
  const folder = "posts/";
  const file = `${folder}${slug}.md`;

  try {
    const content = fs.readFileSync(file, "utf8");
    const matterResult = matter(content);
    return matterResult;
  } catch (error) {
    const notFoundContent = "Article not found";
    const notFoundMatterResult = matter(notFoundContent);
    return notFoundMatterResult;
  }
};
```

In local, all the articles are rendered as expected, but when I try the site on Vercel directly goes to the catch block.

Hope somebody can help me, thank you!

Comment: I am facing the same issue. did you have any luck with this issue?